# Paypal Express Checkout popup window issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am implementing Paypal's Express Checkout demo. I just changed the Client ID to be my app's. once I click 'checkout' a popup windows appears and disappears few seconds later. Help!

Comment: have you clear your cache and cookies then try again?

Comment: @amuroray I just did that and it's still not working.

Comment: @amuroray it is working now. Apparently I had to turn Apache on and put this file in htdocs folder. I have no idea why.

Comment: hmmm express checkout required it to run on a server to emulate it. I thought you were trying on the demo site.

Comment: @amuroray I didn't know that, I thought a simple html and JS file will do the trick but obviously I was mistaken. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Most of time this happens because opencart doesn't update the environment form sandbox to live in code, when you configure in the backend.

To solve this out go to

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/payment/pp_express.twig
```

And in javascript change the line

```
environment: 'sandbox'
```

to

```
environment: '{{ environment }}'
```

And then clear the cache. Once the cache is cleared, you are good to go.